# Show/Hide Cells in a CollectionView -Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview with 3 columns and 20 rows. I want to show only first 3 rows and put a "Show More" button at the bottom of the collection view. When user touches the button, other rows will be visible.
I can't do this. So I created two different collection views,  the first collection view contains only 3 rows which I want to show at first time and after clicking the button, other collection view shows.
There is a easier to do this? I want to do this with just one collectionview?

Comment: Why would you think you can't do this? Simply change the return value of `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and call `reloadData` and the cells will be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NSMutableArray as data source:

```
-(void)buttonShowMoreClicked {
  [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.dataSourceArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayContainingInfoAboutOther17Rows];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPaths];
  } completion:nil];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.dataSourceArray.count;
```